# Swift atomic boolean

Tags: swift, thread-safety

I'm trying to create a wrapper around the iOS `OSTestAndSet()` and `OSTestAndClear()` functions for use with an atomic boolean type based on the following [GitHub code](https://gist.github.com/macu/3843eec563e74a5e5804):

```
class AtomicBoolean {

    private var val: Byte = 0

    /// Sets the value, and returns the previous value.
    /// The test/set is an atomic operation.
    func testAndSet(value: Bool) -> Bool {
        if value {
            return OSAtomicTestAndSet(0, &val)
        } else {
             return OSAtomicTestAndClear(0, &val)
        }
    }

    /// Returns the current value of the boolean.
    /// The value may change before this method returns.
    func test() -> Bool {
        return val != 0
    }

}
```

However, I'm getting a compiler error for the property declaration that says: `Use of undeclared type 'Byte'; did you mean to use 'UInt8'?`

Currently, I'm importing Foundation for this code file. I've seen other stackoverflow posts use the Byte type but I haven't been able to find why this isn't available in my case.

I'm using the following version of Swift:
Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)

Furthermore, if I change the datatype to UInt8 as the compiler suggests, I receive additional errors on the OSAtomicTestAndSet() and OSAtomicTestAndClear() calls that states the following: `Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'UInt8'` despite the fact that I'm using a `var` declaration and not a `let`.

Comment: `Byte` was removed as a typealias in Swift 1.2 (I think and not earlier).  Use `UInt8` instead.  I'm not seeing your second error in Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2).

Comment: @vacawama Thanks. For the second error, I was trying to define it as a struct instead of a class but I guess that doesn't work with pointers. I'm honestly not familiar with these details of Swift yet.

Comment: Check out my answer below. byte works with a typealias and struct works with mutating keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typealias` of `Byte` to `UInt8` was removed and no longer exists in Swift 1.2.  You can define it yourself, or just use `UInt8` (the better option).

In the comments, you said the immutable problem was that you are using a `struct` instead of a `class`.  You can use `struct`, you just have to add the keyword `mutating` to any function that modifies the `struct`:

```
typealias Byte = UInt8

struct AtomicBoolean {

    private var val: Byte = 0

    /// Sets the value, and returns the previous value.
    /// The test/set is an atomic operation.
    mutating func testAndSet(value: Bool) -> Bool {
        if value {
            return OSAtomicTestAndSet(0, &val)
        } else {
            return OSAtomicTestAndClear(0, &val)
        }
    }

    /// Returns the current value of the boolean.
    /// The value may change before this method returns.
    func test() -> Bool {
        return val != 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the implementation of this class is bogous. It sets bit #0 which is the most significant, instead of bit #7 which is the least significant. This is the correct implementation :

```
public class AtomicBoolean {  
  private var val: UInt8 = 0

  public init(initialValue: Bool) {
    self.val = (initialValue == false ? 0 : 1)
  }

  public func getAndSet(value: Bool) -> Bool {
    if value {
      return  OSAtomicTestAndSet(7, &val)
    } else {
      return  OSAtomicTestAndClear(7, &val)
    }
  }

  public func get() -> Bool {
    return val != 0
  }
}
```

And a test to verify :

```
public class AtomicTest: XCTestCase {

  func testSimple() {
    let x = AtomicBoolean(initialValue: true)
    XCTAssertTrue(x.get())
    XCTAssertTrue(x.get())
    XCTAssertTrue(x.getAndSet(true))
    XCTAssertTrue(x.getAndSet(false))
    XCTAssertFalse(x.get())
    XCTAssertFalse(x.getAndSet(true))
    XCTAssertTrue(x.get())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 Beta 4, Swift 2.0, is happy with the following, which is pretty much your code with "UInt8" vs "Byte":

```
class AtomicBoolean {

    private var val: UInt8 = 0

    func testAndSet(value: Bool) -> Bool {
        if value {
            return OSAtomicTestAndSet(0, &val)
        } else {
            return OSAtomicTestAndClear(0, &val)
        }
    }

    func test() -> Bool {
        return val != 0
    }
}
```